# Passing State to an Protected Route in Vue Router (script setup method)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

Halo friends, I need to send a state to the protected routes in vue-router. But while doing so I faced the error.

```bash
Discarded invalid param(s) "_id", "dish_name", "description", "img", "ingredients", "instructions", "cooking_time", "chef", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "__v" when navigating. 
See https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22 for more details.
```

I cant get the params in the protected routes,why?

Here are my codes

The route.js file

```
export const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/reciepe/:id',
      name: 'individual-reciepe',
      component: SingleReciepe
    },
    {
      path: '/create_reciepe',
      name: 'create_reciepe',
      component: CreateReciepe,
      meta:{
        auth:true,
      },
      props:true,
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        auth: false
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'register',
      component: Register
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isAuthenticated = isAuth()
  console.log(isAuthenticated)
  if (!isAuthenticated && 'auth' in to.meta && to.meta.auth) {
    next('/login')
  } else if (isAuthenticated && 'auth' in to.meta && !to.meta.auth) {
    next('/')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
export default router
```

The function in which i'am routing to a protected route

```
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter(),
  route = useRoute();

function editReciepe() {
  console.log('in the edit')
  router.push({ name: 'create_reciepe', params:  reciepe.value  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, if you follow the link provided in the error you've shown, it will explain the issue (https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22)

Comment: can you describe what result you expect?

Comment: @ManhDo ,I need the params value (i.e) reciepe value to be passed to the create_reciepe page.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to pass data from route. I know two ways to do it.

the first way, you can use `props` on route like: (Option API way)

```js
const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: [
    ...,
    {
      name: 'team-members',
      path: ':id',
      component: TeamMembers,
      props: true,
    }
    ,,,,    
  ]
})
```

and map data to component by `props` property:

```
export default {
    props: ['id']
}
```

consume route:

```js
<router-link :to="'/teams/' + valuePassToRoute">View Members</router-link>
```

or

```js
this.$router.push({name: 'team-members', params: { id: value },});
```

get data from route:

```js
const id = this.$route.params.id;
```

this is detail information `#route`, value is `t1`

[image]

if you use `query` or `meta` property, it is not much different.

consume route:

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'team-members', params: { id: this.id }, query: { sort: 'asc' }};
```

get data:

```js
const value = this.$route.query.sort;
```

the second way: (Composition API)

```js
<script>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
export default {
    props: ['id'],
    setup() {
        const route = useRoute();
        const value = route.params.id
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: if you feel it useful, please [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or accept answer